# How can I take an SQL DUMP and modify it to fit a different database table structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

I'm having tremendous trouble upgrading my shopping cart software on my website, due to changes in the database structure, such as different ordering of columns and sometimes even new columns. What I was thinking of doing, is taking my old SQL DUMP files, and formatting them to fit the new structure, just this once, so I can it working. How can this be done?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past using a more tactical, if not brute-force approach.

I wrote some code to parse the DML statements from the dump file and turned each statement into a data structure.  The data structure can then be used to populate a format string that resembles the DML required by the target schema.  Then just write the format string out to a new file (and repeat).

Comment: So what your saying is, I could use for example, PHP, to connect to the DB, extract the information I need and use a loop to output a string in the correct dump format for my new database?

Comment: You could do that as well...I was suggesting instead of connecting to the database online, that you create a dump of all of your DML statements and re-format them offline. The script that you write to do the dump parsing, reformatting, and generating of the new DML file could be done with PHP. There's nothing wrong necessarily with querying the records from PHP, I think that using the dump utility and working with the dump files is faster, and it lines up with the need to take the database offline to do the migration.   You can't migrate a database that is still being written to...

Answer (score 1):

Load it in to an empty DB, use SQL to move the data to the format that you want, dump it again, and load it where you finally want it to be.

Comment: I use Squeal Pro to manage my databases, when I move things and re-dump they are just in the same format. I need to remove some columns completely, I can't see a way to do this?

Comment: MySQL isn't my forte. If MySQL won't let you delete columns using ALTER TABLE, then you can create a new table with your new schema, and then insert the correct data in to that table. If MySQL won't let you rename tables, then drop the old table, create it with your old name but new schema, and then copy it back. You'll need to be aware of foreign keys and other relationships that can thwart this process. Just drop or disable them and recreate/reenable them when you're done.